# No DRL files found for the KieBase, using kmodule.xml

Tags: drools

I'm developing a Maven project using java and Drools 6.2.0, and I'm trying to "bind" a certain DRL file to a KieBase through the kmodule.xml file, but I keep getting the error

```
WARN org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule - No files found for KieBase
```

when running the project.

I think I've configured everything the right way, as shown in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch04.html#KIEBuildingSection) (Chapter 4.2.2 - Overview - Build, Deploy, Utilize and Run - Building), but can't see where is my mistake.

In this project, I think it's not an option for me to declare/configure Drools by coding, due to the project architecture, that's why I'm using the kmodule.xml approach.

Any suggestion is welcome.

---

My kmodule.xml (location: src/main/resources/META-INF):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="departureKB" packages="com.site.myapp.checks.departure">
        <ksession name="departureKS" type="stateless" />
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

My DRL file (dummy) (location: src/main/resources/com/site/myapp/checks/departure):

```
package com.site.myapp.checks.departure

rule "my rule 1"
    when
        // some conditions
    then
        // something to do
end
```

My class Departure (only the Drools code) (location: src/com/site/myapp/checks):

```
channelName = "departure";
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kc = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
String kSessionName = channelName+"KS";
kSession = kc.newStatelessKieSession(kSessionName);
```

My pom.xml (only the Drools dependencies) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-bom</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>named-kiesession</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem here. I do have some questions though:

Why are you including drools-bom and named-kiesession artifacts? Do you really need them?

What's the name of your drl file?

Comment: - The drools-bom artifact I'm not sure, it was included by other guy, but I think it's related with the compilation.
- The named-kiesession artifact I've seen it in a tutorial, and have tried it...
- My DRL file name is Departure.drl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that it's needed to declare in the **pom.xml** file to include the DRL files.

The **pom.xml** file should look like this (in my project it's like this, should be similar in others):

```
<project ...>
   ...
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>META-INF/kmodule.xml</include>
                    <include>com/site/myapp/checks/departure/Departure.drl</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>.</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
                <artifactId>drools-bom</artifactId>
                <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Take notice** to the changes related with the pom.xml indicated in the Question.
Here, I've changed the location of the **drools-bom** artifact, it's now in the ***dependecyManagement*** tag (this artifact is used for the version control of the artifacts, with this you only need to declared the version of the artifacts one time); and have removed the **named-kiesession** artifact.